# flask app crashing when I try to run it on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, keras

When I run my flask app on localhost it works fine. But when I try to deploy it on heroku, I get the code=H10 desc="App crashed"  error even though the app is successfully built. Only when I go to the app link it gives an application error.
I am new to flask and Heroku so I tried to search and find how to create a virtual environment and create a Procfile, requirements.txt but I am not sure I did it right. It can't find the keras module even though I imported it into the project and works just fine on the local server.  I checked using pip list

Here are the error messages:

```
2020-11-09T13:36:48.507185+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=digiturk-sentiment-analysis.herokuapp.com request_id=6d897e8d-56fe-491b-b1d8-f8e23714ede7 fwd="212.2.212.159" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-09T13:36:48.827090+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=digiturk-sentiment-analysis.herokuapp.com request_id=0bea3283-fc27-4021-85d5-b02279d5d496 fwd="212.2.212.159" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here is the log I get from running heroku logs --tail

```
2020-11-09T13:08:28.510088+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-11-09T13:08:28.510088+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-11-09T13:08:28.510088+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-11-09T13:08:28.510088+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-11-09T13:08:28.510089+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-11-09T13:08:28.510090+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-11-09T13:08:28.510090+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-11-09T13:08:28.510090+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-11-09T13:08:28.510091+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2020-11-09T13:08:28.510091+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-11-09T13:08:28.510092+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-11-09T13:08:28.510092+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-11-09T13:08:28.510092+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-11-09T13:08:28.510093+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
2020-11-09T13:08:28.510093+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
2020-11-09T13:08:28.510094+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-11-09T13:08:28.510094+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 3, in <module>
2020-11-09T13:08:28.510094+00:00 app[web.1]: from model import predict
2020-11-09T13:08:28.510095+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/model.py", line 2, in <module>
2020-11-09T13:08:28.510095+00:00 app[web.1]: from keras.models import load_model
2020-11-09T13:08:28.510151+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
2020-11-09T13:08:28.511285+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-09 13:08:28 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-11-09T13:08:28.560808+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-09 13:08:28 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-11-09T13:08:28.560912+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-09 13:08:28 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-11-09T13:08:28.636728+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-11-09T13:08:28.692601+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-11-09T13:30:47.950776+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-11-09T13:30:52.025068+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command gunicorn app:app --log-file=-
2020-11-09T13:30:54.332535+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-09 13:30:54 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-11-09T13:30:54.333199+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-09 13:30:54 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:13741 (4)
2020-11-09T13:30:54.333298+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-09 13:30:54 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-11-09T13:30:54.337230+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-09 13:30:54 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-11-09T13:30:54.342063+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-09 13:30:54 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-11-09T13:30:54.705176+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757837+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-09 13:30:54 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757878+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757879+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757880+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757880+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757881+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757881+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757881+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757882+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757882+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757882+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757883+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757883+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757883+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757884+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757884+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757884+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757885+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757885+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757886+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757886+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757886+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757887+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757887+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757887+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 3, in <module>
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757888+00:00 app[web.1]: from model import predict
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757888+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/model.py", line 2, in <module>
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757888+00:00 app[web.1]: from keras.models import load_model
2020-11-09T13:30:54.757897+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
2020-11-09T13:30:54.758286+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-09 13:30:54 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761485+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-09 13:30:54 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761486+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761486+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761487+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761487+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761488+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761488+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761489+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761489+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761490+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761490+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761490+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761491+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761491+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761491+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761492+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761492+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761493+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761493+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761494+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761494+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761494+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761495+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761495+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761496+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 3, in <module>
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761496+00:00 app[web.1]: from model import predict
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761497+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/model.py", line 2, in <module>
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761497+00:00 app[web.1]: from keras.models import load_model
2020-11-09T13:30:54.761502+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
2020-11-09T13:30:54.762175+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-09 13:30:54 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2020-11-09T13:30:54.906160+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-09 13:30:54 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-11-09T13:30:54.906304+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-09 13:30:54 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-11-09T13:30:54.974612+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-11-09T13:30:55.020352+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Comment: You are missing a module: `No module named 'keras'`

Comment: Hello, when I type `pip list ` on the terminal it shows that keras is installed. What else can be the problem?